# Output array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm a little way through solving my task of creating a dropdown containing the insurance companies, then a second dropdown showing the insurance types that insurance company offers e.g. property, fleet or motortrade (insurance type offered incudes a number).) Once both select dropdowns have been selected display the relevant number.

At the moment this is as far as I've got thanks to some help below http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoEiL

Heres the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get" class="insurance-numbers">
  <div>
    <select id="company">

    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="insurance-type">

    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="insurance-number"></div>
</form>
```

And Javascript:

```
var insurancecompanies = [
  { 
    name : 'Advent', 
    property : '01242 674 674', 
    fleet : '', 
    motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Allianz', 
   property : '0844 412 9988', 
   fleet : '0800 587 5858', 
   motortrade : '' 
  },
  {   name : 'Aviva', 
   property : '0800 015 1498', 
   fleet : '0800 246 876', 
   motortrade : '0800 246 876'
  },
  {   name : 'AXA', 
   property : '0870 900 0867', 
   fleet : '0870 900 0860', 
   motortrade : '0870 900 1753'
  },
  {   name : 'Catlin', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '0800 066 5364', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Chartis', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '0844 477 6544', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Clegg Gifford', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '', 
   motortrade : '01708 729 529'
  },
  {   name : 'Equity Red Star', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '0845 609 1235', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Highway/LV', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '0845 373 1244', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'NIG', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '0845 300 4644', 
   motortrade : '0845 300 4644'
  },
  {   name : 'QBE', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '01245 272 700', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Royal Sun Alliance', 
   property : '0845 077 0120', 
   fleet : '0845 675 0404', 
   motortrade : '0845 077 0119' 
  },
  {   name : 'Summit', 
   property : '', 
   fleet : '01254 396 655', 
   motortrade : ''
  },
  {   name : 'Zurich', 
   property : '0845 300 2055', 
   fleet : '0800 300 2055', 
   motortrade : ''
  }
];


function findCompany(name) {
  var i = 0, len = insurancecompanies.length;
  for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
    if (insurancecompanies[i].name === name) {
      return insurancecompanies[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
};

var dropdown = [], i = 0, len = insurancecompanies.length;
for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
  dropdown.push(insurancecompanies[i].name);
}

$.each( dropdown, function( i, val ) {
  $("#company").append( "<option val=\""+ val +"\">" + val + "</option>" );
});

$('#company').on('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    var selectedInsurance = findCompany(valueSelected);
    for (i in selectedInsurance) {
      $("#insurance-type").append( "<option val=\""+ selectedInsurance[i] +"\">" + selectedInsurance[i] + "</option>" );
    }
});
```

At the moment it displays the list of insurance companies correctly. It then selects the company chosen on change. I need it to then display the insurance types it offers (ignoring the ones it dosn't (ones with no numbers) then upon that selection display the number in the div#insurance-number.

So to demonstarte if i selected Allianz, the second dropdown would contain 'property' and 'fleet'. If the user selected 'fleet' the number '0800 587 5858' would get appended to the div#insurance-number'.

sorry if this is confusing I really need some help with this that is all.

Comment: The trailing commas in the array literals are invalid in some browsers. Otherwise, whether your code is right rather depends on how you're planning to use it...

Comment: not quite sure what this array has to do with object oriented programming. or jQuery for that matter.

Comment: Clarify "ouput". Currently there is no output because you only defined a variable.

Comment: What is your question? On the right track for what? And where do you want the output to go / be used for?

Comment: I don't really get the question

Comment: As he said he's new to OOP, he isn't sure how to access the objets properties. See my answer @Rob

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create a dropdown of options based on the `name` property of each object in the array then you'd do something like this:

```
var dropdown = [], i = 0, len = insurancecompanies.length;
for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
  dropdown.push(insurancecompanies[i].name);
}
```

Use `dropdown` to populate your select.
Then use the selected option and find the corresponding object in the array by traversing it:

```
function findCompany(name) {
  var i = 0, len = insurancecompanies.length;
  for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
    if (insurancecompanies[i].name === name) {
      return insurancecompanies[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

***UPDATE***: you need to add an `change` event on the `company` select. On change, apply `findCompany(selectedOption)` and then populate the second select but instead of iterating the array you're going to have to iterate the object properties more or less like so:

```
var selectedInsurance = findCompany(selectedOption); // selectedOption is the value of the first select 

for (i in selectedInsurance) {
  // here add to your dropdown selectedInsurance[i]
}
```

Comment: Thank Joe, please see my codepen, only got as far as displaying the dropdown, could you help with the rest? [link]http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoEiL

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your help so far, I've made an edit to my OP, please have a look and if you can provide any further help that would be most welcome. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To access the object properties use something like `myArray[index].property`

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPub5/) accessing the object property 'name'.

If you want to output the whole object replace `(insurancecompanies[i].name)` with `console.log(insurancecompanies[i])` and view your console log.

To populate the select menu like you asked for with javascript use something like bellow [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPub5/5/)

```
var insurancecompanies = [
{ 
    name : 'Advent', 
    property : '01242 674 674', 
    fleet : '', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Allianz', 
    property : '0844 412 9988', 
    fleet : '0800 587 5858', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Aviva', 
    property : '0800 015 1498', 
    fleet : '0800 246 876', 
    motortrade : '0800 246 876'
},
{   name : 'AXA', 
    property : '0870 900 0867', 
    fleet : '0870 900 0860', 
    motortrade : '0870 900 1753'
},
{   name : 'Catlin', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '0800 066 5364', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Chartis', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '0844 477 6544', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Clegg Gifford', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '', 
    motortrade : '01708 729 529'
},
{   name : 'Equity Red Star', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '0845 609 1235', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Highway/LV', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '0845 373 1244', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'NIG', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '0845 300 4644', 
    motortrade : '0845 300 4644'
},
{   name : 'QBE', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '01245 272 700', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Royal Sun Alliance', 
    property : '0845 077 0120', 
    fleet : '0845 675 0404', 
    motortrade : '0845 077 0119'
},
{   name : 'Summit', 
    property : '', 
    fleet : '01254 396 655', 
    motortrade : ''
},
{   name : 'Zurich', 
    property : '0845 300 2055', 
    fleet : '0800 300 2055', 
    motortrade : ''
}
];

function foo() {

   select = document.getElementById('foo');

   for (var i=0; i<insurancecompanies.length; i++){
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = insurancecompanies[i].name;
      select.appendChild(opt);
   }

}

foo();
```

Comment: thanks Aaron, if you see my codepen [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoEiL) I've populated the dropdown, I now intend to use the selected option and find the corresponding object in the array by populating another dropdown consisting of the available types of insurance. e.g. Chartis offers insurance in fleet, so the dropdown would show 'fleet'. then somehow display the number?!